# sql string or binary data truncated

Tags: c#, sql-server, insert

i use ASP.NET and SQL 2008 R2. this mlessage meant i have the data that over the limit in my table. but how can i find/show message to user which column that cause this problem ?

```
 public static void Put_CSVtoSQL_PerLine(string LeFile)
        {

            string line = null;
            bool IsFirst = true;
            string SqlSyntax = Outils.LoadFileToString(Path.Combine(appDir, @"SQL\InsertLV_Temp_Gros.sql"));

            int NOID, ENLEV_UNITE, NBR_COLIS, FACTURATION, TRANSPORTEUR, CHAUFFEUR;
            DateTime DATE_CLOTURE;
            decimal POID,ENLEV_CREMB, ENLEV_DECL;
            bool LIVRS_SIGN, LIVRS_SAMD, IS_PRINT, IS_IMPORT;

            object  CODE_DEST, CODE_CLIENT,  MODAL_MODE, LIBELLE_PORT, LIBELLE_EXPR, LIBELLE_UNITE,   RS_NOM_EXP;
            object ADDR_EXP, CP_EXP, VILLE_EXP, TEL_EXP, FAX_EXP, RS_NOM_DEST, ADDR_DEST, CP_DEST, INSEE_DEST, LE_ZONE, VILLE_DEST, TEL_DEST, FAX_DEST;
            object NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL,  CODE_MAG,  OBS, LIB_AGENCE, LIB_TOURNE;
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(LeFile))
                {
                    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] data = line.Split(';');

                        if (data.Length > 0)
                        {
                            if (!IsFirst)
                            {
                                string[] data_Innen = data[0].Split(',');
                                if (data_Innen.Length == 38)
                                {
                                    NOID = Convert.ToInt32(data_Innen[0].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    CODE_DEST = data_Innen[1].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    CODE_CLIENT = data_Innen[2].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    DATE_CLOTURE = Convert.ToDateTime(data_Innen[3].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    MODAL_MODE = data_Innen[4].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    LIBELLE_PORT = data_Innen[5].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    LIBELLE_EXPR = data_Innen[6].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    ENLEV_UNITE = Convert.ToInt32(data_Innen[7].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    LIBELLE_UNITE = data_Innen[8].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    NBR_COLIS = Convert.ToInt32(data_Innen[9].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    POID = Convert.ToDecimal(data_Innen[10].Replace('\'', ' ').Replace('.', ',').Trim());
                                    ENLEV_CREMB = Convert.ToDecimal(data_Innen[11].Replace('\'', ' ').Replace('.', ',').Trim());
                                    ENLEV_DECL = Convert.ToDecimal(data_Innen[12].Replace('\'', ' ').Replace('.', ',').Trim());
                                    RS_NOM_EXP = data_Innen[13].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    ADDR_EXP = data_Innen[14].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    CP_EXP = data_Innen[15].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    VILLE_EXP = data_Innen[16].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    TEL_EXP = data_Innen[17].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    FAX_EXP = data_Innen[18].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    RS_NOM_DEST = data_Innen[19].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    ADDR_DEST = data_Innen[20].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    CP_DEST = data_Innen[21].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    INSEE_DEST = data_Innen[22].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    VILLE_DEST = data_Innen[23].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    TEL_DEST = data_Innen[24].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    FAX_DEST = data_Innen[25].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    IS_PRINT = Convert.ToBoolean(data_Innen[26].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    IS_IMPORT = Convert.ToBoolean(data_Innen[27].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    CHAUFFEUR = Convert.ToInt32(data_Innen[28].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL = data_Innen[29].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    TRANSPORTEUR = Convert.ToInt32(data_Innen[30].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    CODE_MAG = data_Innen[31].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    FACTURATION = Convert.ToInt32(data_Innen[32].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    LIVRS_SIGN = Convert.ToBoolean(data_Innen[33].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    LIVRS_SAMD = Convert.ToBoolean(data_Innen[34].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim());
                                    OBS = data_Innen[35].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    LIB_AGENCE = data_Innen[36].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
                                    LIB_TOURNE = data_Innen[37].Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();

                                    using (var connectionWrapper = new Connexion())
                                    {
                                        var connectedConnection = connectionWrapper.GetConnected();
                                        SqlCommand comm_Insert = new SqlCommand(SqlSyntax, connectionWrapper.conn);

                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOID", NOID);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE_DEST", CODE_DEST);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE_CLIENT", CODE_CLIENT);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_CLOTURE", DATE_CLOTURE);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODAL_MODE", MODAL_MODE);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIBELLE_PORT", LIBELLE_PORT);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIBELLE_EXPR", LIBELLE_EXPR);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENLEV_UNITE", ENLEV_UNITE);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIBELLE_UNITE", LIBELLE_UNITE);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NBR_COLIS", NBR_COLIS);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POID", POID);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENLEV_CREMB", ENLEV_CREMB);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENLEV_DECL", ENLEV_DECL);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RS_NOM_EXP", RS_NOM_EXP);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDR_EXP", ADDR_EXP);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CP_EXP", CP_EXP);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VILLE_EXP", VILLE_EXP);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEL_EXP", TEL_EXP);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FAX_EXP", FAX_EXP);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RS_NOM_DEST", RS_NOM_DEST);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDR_DEST", ADDR_DEST);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CP_DEST", CP_DEST);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INSEE_DEST", INSEE_DEST);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VILLE_DEST", VILLE_DEST);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEL_DEST", TEL_DEST);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FAX_DEST", FAX_DEST);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IS_PRINT", IS_PRINT);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IS_IMPORT", IS_IMPORT);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHAUFFEUR", CHAUFFEUR);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL", NO_ORDRE_CUMMUL);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TRANSPORTEUR", TRANSPORTEUR);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE_MAG", CODE_MAG);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FACTURATION", FACTURATION);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIVRS_SIGN", LIVRS_SIGN);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIVRS_SAMD", LIVRS_SAMD);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OBS", OBS);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIB_AGENCE", LIB_AGENCE);
                                        comm_Insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LIB_TOURNE", LIB_TOURNE);

                                        comm_Insert.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                    }
                                }                              
                            }

                            IsFirst = false;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw new Exception("Err CSV to SQL" + LeFile + "--" + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
```

in my catch exception:

```
catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    throw new Exception("Err CSV to SQL" + WHICH COLUMN ??? + "--" + ex.Message, ex);
                }
```

Comment: Unfortunately SQL Server does not return that highly useful information. Consider upvoting [new virtual table: errors. It would analogous to the deleted and inserted tables](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/774754/new-virtual-table-errors-it-would-analogous-to-the-deleted-and-inserted-tables) and or [Please fix the "String or binary data would be truncated" message to give the column name](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion here is the two ways that will help you

**Method 1**

As you said one of the columns in table is being sent an object that is larger than its bounds.

I would recommend you should add a break point to look deeper the values that you are passing in and  then you are very easily compare the one with the field in table to verify where the conflict is and then modify your definitions accordingly.

**Method 2**

Also you can debug it in sql , here is the link from where you can read more http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/how-to-find-what-column

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what are the constraints for the columns in  the c# code ?

If you so, are you validating your data before saving ?

Relying on getting answer from database is the most expensive and time-consuming way of checking if field's length is withing some range, especially when you had access to it via the user interface an you could save db roundtrip